# Array#sample random numbers generator

Tags: ruby

How does `Array#sample` work, if you pass a range as random numbers generator?
As here :

```
> [*1..10].sample(random: 1..3)
=>9
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the doc, [`sample(random: rng)`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample), `rng` is not a `Range` Object, as you might thought. `rng` is a *Random* number generator.

> The optional rng argument will be used as the random number generator.

```
a = (1..10).to_a
r = Random.new
r2 = r.dup
a1 = a.sample(random: r)
a2 = a.sample(random: r2)
a1 == a2 # => true
```

The point is `#sample`, takes its *second argument as keyword argument*. If we use something like `foo: 12` or `rng: (1..2)`, it will give **ArgumentError: unknown keyword:**. The *optional argument* will be acceptable only when you will supply it a value as `random: <any random number generator>`. Now, coming to your point :

```
r = 1..3
a1 = [*1..10].sample(random: r)
a2 = [*1..10].sample(random: r)
a1 == a2 # => false
```

When you are passing the second argument as `random: r`, `r` must be [`Random`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Random.html) object, or an *object* that responds to [`#rand`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand). Remember with the *second* argument, you are telling `#sample`, to use your *random number generator* instead of the **default** one it uses in absence of the optional argument.

Here is one *custom* implementation of a *RNG* :

```
ob = Object.new

def ob.to_int
  5000
end

gen_to_int = proc do |max|
  ob
end

class << gen_to_int
  alias rand call
end

ary = (0...10000).to_a

ary.sample(random: gen_to_int) # => 5000
ary.sample(random: gen_to_int) # => 5000
ary.sample(random: gen_to_int) # => 5000
```

This will give you the understanding about `#sample` with the *optional* argument. Look for more examples from [`#test_sample_random`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/test/ruby/test_array.rb#L2271).

**Update**

> How does `Array#sample` work, if you pass a *range* as random numbers generator?

To answer this, I would take a help of the [`TracePoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/TracePoint.html) class.

```
trace = TracePoint.new(:c_call) do |tp|
  p [tp.lineno, tp.defined_class, tp.method_id, tp.event]
end

trace.enable do
  [1,2,3,4,5,66,4].sample(random: 1..3)
end
# >> [6, Array, :sample, :c_call]
# >> [6, Kernel, :rand, :c_call]
# >> [6, Kernel, :respond_to_missing?, :c_call]
```

So, from the above *call stack*, you can see - `Array#sample` method has been called. Now internally, Ruby called `Kernel#rand` on the `Range` object. Now, `(1..3).respond_to?` returned `false`(because `#rand` - it is  a_private_ instance method for `Range`), that's why finally `#respond_to_missing?` method has been called to do the job.

Comment: So this method checks if `rng` in `sample(random: rng)` is actually a random number generator? Could you explain how?

Comment: @zerozero7 How means ? I gave you examples.. Still not convinced.. :-)

Comment: How - in terms how the method knows, that supplied value is indeed a random number generator, not a range object for example. I understand your examples, I didn't mean to be rude. Just curious how the method actually omits optional argument.

Comment: Through the key `random`... It will understand.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Yes,, that's strange. It silently ignores.

Comment: @Ajedi32 I gave one example to show how the method call chains are going in general.

Comment: @Ajedi32 yes.. It is.. :-)

Comment: I still consider the lack of an error to be strange behavior though, given that `(1..3).rand` results in ``NoMethodError: private method `rand' called for 1..3:Range``. Maybe the `sample` method in the Ruby core should be updated to check that `rand` is public.

Comment: @Ajedi32 If you'd look at the implementation pointed in the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681596/arraysample-random-numbers-generator/28681822?noredirect=1#comment45674373_28681822) you'll see `rand` method is sent to an object so it effectively bypasses visibility scope declared with `Module#private` or `Module#protected` methods. I'd agree the docs should be updated to reflect that case.

Comment: @DavidUnric Right. I'm saying though that rather than updating the docs to explain this unexpected behavior, the implementation should be changed to actually fix the problem. (I'm not very familiar with the MRI internals though, even after reading the code you linked, so maybe there's some technical reason why this can't be fixed that I'm missing?)

Comment: @Ajedi32 I mentioned it _earlier_ only, the _object_ you will pass through the _optional_ argument, it must respond to `#rand`. That's clear, from the _custom generator_ that I have shown. `Kernel#rand` method is _private_, and for some API like `Random` class overrides this as their public API.

Comment: @Ajedi32 please see now.

Comment: Nice. Looks good. I'd upvote, but I did that already and can't upvote twice. ;-)